# What is the meaning of the symbol | in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am new to TypeScript and came across the symbol | while solving LeetCode problem using
Typescript. I guess it defines default variable type. Can someone elaborate it.

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * class TreeNode {
 *     val: number
 *     left: TreeNode | null
 *     right: TreeNode | null
 *     constructor(val?: number, left?: TreeNode | null, right?: TreeNode | null) {
 *         this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
 *         this.left = (left===undefined ? null : left)
 *         this.right = (right===undefined ? null : right)
 *     }
 * }
 */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html:

> A union type describes a value that can be one of several types. We use the vertical bar (`|`) to separate each type, so `number | string | boolean` is the type of a value that can be a `number`, a `string`, or a `boolean`.